Is logic a language?
This is a follow through of a question I asked earlier this month: Is math (only) a language?. The answer that made the most sense was one that alluded to the laws of nature being mathematical. Please follow the link above if you're curious.
Today, looking at question that asks if there's a difference between mathematical logic and philosophical logic, I remembered reading about logicism, an enterprise dedicated to reducing math to logic (for more visit SEP/Wiki).
Sequitur ...
If there's reason to believe math is a language and  for the reason that math is an extension of logic (per logicism), there's reason to believe logic is also a language.
Is logic a language?
Arigato gozaimas.
P. S. Please feel free to include your views on whether math is a language as the 2 seem to be conjoined twins that need to be delivered simultaneously so to speak.

See sect.2.1: logic is strictly connected with language.

Does logic include specialized language? Yes. Is that language all there is to it? No. The task of language is to enable expression of some content, logic does more than that when it classifies said content as valid or invalid, etc. The same is true of any formal system, in mathematics, physics, etc. It has (at least) two components, formal language is only one of them. The other is a proof system for expressions of that language. And it extends to informal theories as well, they are more than languages when they regiment evidence and arguments.

define language, define logic, etc. is a hotdog a sandwich

@MauroALLEGRANZA, arigato gozaimus. Will get to reading that article ASAP. In the mean time, I'd like to know what you personally think about the matter. Is logic a language? I ask because this is one my long unanswered questions. What I know is logic doesn't concern itself with semantics and it comes with a set of symbols, whose use is governed by the rules that stipulate what a well-formed formula is.

@Conifold, I suppose what I want to know is the similarities/dissimilarities between logic and natural languages like English. Can you read my reply to MauroALLEGRANZO (*vide supra)?

@Kaia, Language: communication medium + ? Logic: A system of rules by which given some initial truths (premises), we arrive at a further truth (the conclusion),

Logic is a topic, discipline, field of study and not a "faculty" of the mind. Since it's beginning in the Western world with Aristotle, logic is deeply involved with language, because logic deals with terms (and their reference), statements (and their meaning), arguments (and their validity=truth preservation).

But this does not mean that logic IS a language. It means that logic is impossible without language.

Some logicians consider logic to be rooted in grammar and to be fundamentally linguistic in nature. This is true of Buridan and Quine, for example. Also some logicians consider the development of formal logic to be a search for an ideal language, i.e. one in which ambiguities are impossible and inferences are straightforward to evaluate.

The SEP entry about different conceptions of logic that @MauroALLEGRANZA pointed at gives a very good overview of how "logic" is usually defined nowadays. It mentions four, basic ways of viewing (or defining) "logic":

the study of artificial, formal languages
the study of formally valid inference and logical consequence
the study of logical truth
the study of general features, or form, of judgements (thought)

Note that all ways have the word 'study' in them. In other words, "logic" is, in each of these closely related senses, seen as either a science or a field of inquiry, a research field. "Logic" is not "a language", but it studies particular forms of language use, and creates special artificial languages as object of study. Of course, it also expresses itself in a language and creates its own vocabulary of technical terms to refer to (for instance) logical inference rules (modus ponens, modus tollens, syllogism, etc) or to particular parts of the studied language games (premisses, conclusion, etc).
In general the object of study is rational, valid reasoning, as expressed in some language (or as expressible in any language). The focus is on the steps someone may take in an argument: Are each of those steps valid, permissible, persuasive (to rational agents)? How can we link them all up to come to a valid, reliable conclusion (assuming the premisses are true)? When we look at "the "logic of an argument", we abstract from (ignore) whether or not each  separate statement is true; we only look at how the steps are linked up. In a logical analysis (or a more general theory) we may try to formulate a minimal system of rules (general schemas) of valid inference (valid linkage).
In a metaphorical sense, you could then say that "logic", as a particular system of rules, is "the language of valid inference", or even "the language of reasoning". Going one step further, some philosophers in the past have seen it as "the language of thought" (e.g. Leibniz, early Wittgenstein "The logical picture of facts is the thought", Jerry Fodor). However, this last expression can easily be very misleading. It suggests there is only one Logic (with capital L) that somehow magically rules (or should rule) all "valid, rational thought". It suggests an essentialist (platonist, realist) picture of "thought" where we don't establish rules (by simple mutual agreement and public criteria), but discover rules that themselves are as hard, contingent, and "objectively given" as brute facts. It also ignores the fact that "logical reasoning" refers to various activities, various language games, that may require (or allow) very different rules (think of modal logic studying ways of using modal operators like "is necessary", "is possible" versus classic propositional calculus or think of paraconsistent logics).
Every actual system of rules is, imo, always limited, based on idealizations, models that ignore certain aspects of lived experience or behavior, and set up for specific, pragmatic purposes. Systems of logic capture certain aspects of certain language games, but not all of natural language. And all of language cannot capture all of thought, perception, or experience.
If you're interested in the "language" or "logic" of thought in a wider sense (sentient awareness), it might be that the apparently self-contradictory, paraconsistent logic of Nargarjuna ("emptiness is itself empty") is a more useful model than Western classic logics. Or perhaps the playful logical illogic of Zhuangzi's Happy Fish or his Butterfly Dream.

Si, there are different logics for different occasions; unorthodox logics are probably more suitable in most discourse (as you seem to have discovered). Does that make logic a language/not? In what sense is Leibniz using "language" in his assertion that logic is the language of thought? Gracias for linking Zhuangzhi

For Leibniz, see for instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Arte_Combinatoria
This could also be seen as a precursor of semiotics (the theory of signs) which is - in some sense - more foundational than logic (for instance: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-semiotics/)

I never really studied Leibniz, but apparently he had an idea of a rational calculus of thought (based on/using his "characteristica universalis") - which is a precursor of the logicist/formalist project in math (but much more ambitious in scope). These kind of ideas also made him sympathetic towards the Yi Ching (encounter with Chinese philosophy was just starting in 17th century).

I mean let's do the Derrida thing and let's look at both sides here:
1 - Logic is a language:
Wittgensteinians rejoice, logic is a language game, symbols gain meaning through their contextual use, the language of logic is lifted and equated to  the implicit rules that logicians follow, that their proofs, words and symbols follow. And if logic is a language game then there one can consider the language used in that game as such, logic as the game and the language.
Another view is that, yes, logic is a language, because it could serve as a means of communication, of exteriorization, as the substrate of the rationalizing discourse. I can convey ideas using logical propositions, logical proofs, and tirades about logic itself (the meta-logic literature as an expression of logic).
1 - Logic is NOT a language:
Logic is first not a complete language, and thus not a language at all. Logic, for instance, can barely capture issues of intentionality, and logic relies fully on prepositions, subsumes a strict mythologised prepositional calculus wherein the empty claims of logic get imbued with meaning, and that is just language itself. Logic thus becomes a parasite placed on top of language, a tool for its analysis at best, but cannot convey anything unless the parent organism does all the work of semantically grounding logical prepositions until logic becomes merely tautology, and we can exclaim "O yes, my logical proposition is correct, my logical system is valid, all cheer for I have found  Truth!". In more seriousness, logic thus feel more like an attempt at a meta-language, which seems detached from the language it analyses.
Logic might also be considered to not be a language in the analytical sense. It does not have verbs, nouns, complements, determinants et cetera. In fact, logic actively tries to remove complexity and ambiguity so that it is able to say anything at all. Just like mathematics, logic is only a language when it is taken loosely, metaphorically, standing in as the referent for callbacks meant to edify arguments, "Yeah, I'm doing better, the first derivative of my happiness level is positive", says the annoying freshman, and thus the ideal of pure Logic cannot be a language, as it can only ever be analytic, and a language require synthesis.
A jolly 'arigato gozaimus' to you too.

Wittgenstein is apropos, but non liquet as to the exact qualities that make logic a language and the same for why it isn't a language.


Is logic a language?

No, logic is a cognitive capacity.
Formal logic is something else. The expression "Formal logic" may refer either to a language, a corpus of sentences in that language, or a theory of logic.
Mathematics is essentially a corpus of systems of axioms and the theorems derived from them, hopefully logically. Theorems are sentences couched in the mathematical language.
The idea of reducing mathematics to formal logic is, or should be, the idea of rephrasing the whole of mathematics into formal logic sentences.
A computer will do that once we really understand logic. Bertrand Russell never had a chance.
I'm not convinced it would be useful, though. Maybe to verify mathematics?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
